# Need to multiply two columns of one table and substract this result from another column of different table

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns `allocationfee` and `rate` from 
`class` table, need to mutiply these two columns and 
need to name it as `surcharge`.
And finally subtract this value from `baserate` column from `Rate` table.
`Class` table and `Rate` table has `rateid` as common field.

I am trying this way but getting error:

```
select BASERATE - t.Surcharge from rate

(select t.Surcharge from 

(select allocationfee*RATE as SolvencySurcharge from rateclass1) as t) as m
```

sample date:

rateclass1

```
classid   rateid    allocationfee  rate   Surcharge(calculated field=allocationfee*RATE)
101         1          20           30      60
102         2          30           50      150
```

Now i need to subtract the surcharge of rateclass1 from `rate` table based on `rateid`.

```
rate  baserate      basearate-surchrge
1       200           140
2       300           150
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What does "error" mean?

Comment: How come 20*30=60 as per derived column value

Comment: is your rate a whole number representation of a percentage so you need to divide it by 100?

Comment: are `class` and `rateclass1` the same table?

Answer (score 2):

You will get desired result from below query.  Don't make the query complex by using sub-queries unnecessarily.

```
select 
r. BASERATE, 
t.allocationfee*t.RATE as surcharge,
(r.BASERATE -t.allocationfee*t.RATE) as substracted_value
from rate r 
join classtable t 
on t.rateid=r.rateid
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Rams solution, but I think you need to understand what's wrong with the code as you wrote it:

```
select BASERATE - t.Surcharge from rate
(select t.Surcharge from 
(select allocationfee*RATE as SolvencySurcharge from rateclass1) as t) as m
```

you should understand that when you select a field from an outer query, the name of the field must match the name of a field in an inner query, so you either need to change your subquery to:

```
(select SolvencySurcharge  from 
    (select allocationfee*RATE as SolvencySurcharge from rateclass1) as t)
```

or:

```
 (select Surcharge from 
    (select allocationfee*RATE as Surcharge from rateclass1) as t)
```

I'm also going to assume your `rate` value as stored represents a percentage, so needs to be divided by 100:

```
select allocationfee*RATE/100 as Surcharge
```

and you're missing the JOIN syntax between your table and outer subquery:

```
select 
   BASERATE - Surcharge 
from 
 rate r inner join
 (select 
   Surcharge, 
   rateID 
 from 
     (select 
       rateID, 
       allocationfee*RATE/100 as Surcharge 
      from 
       rateclass1) t
     ) m on
 r.rateID = m.rateID
```

note you also need to carry through the `rateID` field in your subqueries so you can join it with the `rateID` field in the `rate` table.  Also, you don't need to qualify the outermost `Surcharge` field, but if you did, it would be from your subquery aliased `m`, not `t`.

HTH